# Game with a coins and probability

Tags: probability

> Two players throw up a coin until someone wins five times(not
>   necessary in a row). Assume that they have throw up a coin five
>   times and first player wins three times. How can i calculate the
>   probability of first player's victory?

I feel that i need to approximate my probability space by some finite cases and use Bayes' theorem. But i still have no idea in what way i can approximate by finite subspaces rigorously.

Comment: Not following.  Are they throwing at the same time?  What's a win?  I assume recursive methods are optimal, in any case.

Comment: That is to say:  depending on what the rules of the game turn out to be, I expect it makes sense to speak about $p(n,m)$...the probability that player $A$ will win given that $A$ has won $n$ times and $B$ has won $m$ times.  Then we proceed by backwards induction, given that $p(5,m)=1$ (for $m<5$) and $p(n,5)=0$ if $n<5$), and $p(n,m)=\frac 12p(n+1,m)+\frac 12p(n,m+1)$ or something like that, depending on the details.

Comment: I posted a solution along those lines below.  I'm assuming that one round is just a $50-50$ shot between two players, as in the toss of a fair coin.  Thus, as a remark, one player or the other will surely win by the ninth round.  If something else was intended, please explain.

Comment: Note:  I added a second, simpler solution.  But the backwards induction comes in handy in a lot of situations, so I'll leave that one there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll interpret the game this way:  two players, $A,B$ are tossing a fair coin.  $A$ wins if it comes up $H$, and $B$ wins if it comes up $T$.  The goal is $5$ wins and when we show up, $A$ has won $3$ and $B$ has won $2$.  What is the probability that $A$ eventually prevails?

Two methods:

Method I.

We'll proceed by backwards induction.  We define $p(n,m)$ to be the probability that $A$ eventually wins, given that $A$ has won $n$ games and $B$ has won $m$.  We remark that $$m<5\implies p(5,m)=1\quad \&\quad n<5\implies p(n,5)=0$$

Considering the possible outcomes of the next toss we have the backwards recursion $$p(n,m)=\frac 12 p(n+1,m)+\frac 12p(n,m+1)$$

Thus:  $$p(4,4)=\frac 12p(5,4)+\frac 12p(4,5)=\frac 12$$

(note:  this was also clear from symmetry)

$$p(4,3)=\frac 12p(5,3)+\frac 12p(4,4)=\frac 12+\frac 14=\frac 34$$
$$p(3,4)=\frac12 p(4,4)+\frac 12p(3,5)=\frac 14$$  (Note:  it is generally true that $p(n,m)+p(m,n)=1$).

Now $p(3,3)=\frac 12$ by symmetry.

$$p(4,2)=\frac 12p(5,2)+\frac 12p(4,3)=\frac 12+ \frac 38=\frac 78$$

And finally $$p(3,2)=\frac 12p(4,2)+\frac 12p(3,3)=\frac 7{16}+\frac 14=\frac {11}{16}$$

Method II.

We can do this by straight counting.  Imagine that all nine games are played, despite the fact that a winner will likely be decided before the ninth.  We see that $A$ will win if and only if $H$ comes up at least two times out of the next $4$.  As the probability of any particular string of four tosses is $\frac 1{16}$ we see that the probability $A$ wins is given by:  $$\frac 1{16}\times \left(\binom 42 +\binom 43 +\binom 44\right)=\frac 1{16}\times \left(6+4+1\right)=\frac {11}{16}$$

Comment: ohhh thx. i'am so dumb it was very easy

Comment: Well, I was a bit surprised the count was so easy.  As you saw, my first impulse was to write out the induction which, if a bit tedious, was sure to give a computable result.